# How can I see how a Stack Apps summary looks for a particular app?

Tags: support, meta, stackapps, scripts, apps

When using one of the templates (app/library/script) while writing a question here, the top of the post will contain some HTML comments:

```
<!-- thumbnail: https://example.com/some-image.png -->
<!-- version: 1.0 -->
<!-- tag: a-tag-on-the-post -->
<!-- excerpt: Up to 200 characters of excerpt -->
```

They end up producing a nice 'summary' of the app or script on the [Stack Apps home page](https://stackapps.com/?tab=apps):

> [image]

However, since the list is quite long, is there a way to *search* for a particular app or script and view its summary? The search result pages are formatted the same way as other Stack Exchange sites. I've tried adding [app](/questions/tagged/app) or [script](/questions/tagged/script) but that doesn't magically turn on the 'summary' view ([example](https://stackapps.com/search?q=saviour+%5Bscript%5D)):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

The summary is only visible on Homepage tabs or the /tagged/[tag] endpoint for a few tags.

The following endpoints show the summary in the post list:

- https://stackapps.com/?tab=apps
- https://stackapps.com/?tab=scripts
- https://stackapps.com/questions/tagged/app
- https://stackapps.com/questions/tagged/script
- https://stackapps.com/questions/tagged/library

The search result page doesn't show the summary which causes that you can't find / filter to just your posts.

Maybe if you or others have time, a user script can add this feature.